# How can I give anonymous users access to a new page?

Tags: permissions

I've made an extension (using civix) that includes a page that's designed to be public facing. But I think the default permissions are blocking all anonymous users. How can I give people access to it, if they don't access-civicrm permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your menu xml file the permission for a path defaults to "access CiviCRM" if not otherwise specified.

To specify it as completely open, use `<access_callback>1</access_callback>`

Here's an example: [CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Misc.xml](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Misc.xml#L48)